# How to make method to wait for button cilck?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make method wait for button to be clicked on created form (wihtout stoping application itself) and get values back from it? Something simmilar to how `MessageBox.Show()` is working.

```
        Form oForm = new Form();
        List<TextBox> ListOfTB = new List<TextBox>();
        oForm.Height = 20;
        foreach (FontPair vFont in ListOfFonts)
        {
            Label oLabel = new Label();
            oLabel.Text = vFont.Western;
            oLabel.Top = oForm.Height - 10;
            oLabel.Left = 10;
            TextBox oText = new TextBox();
            oText.Top = oForm.Height - 20;
            oText.Left = 10;
            oForm.Controls.Add(oLabel);
            oForm.Controls.Add(oText);
            ListOfTB.Add(oText);
            oForm.Height += 20;
        }
        Button oButton = new Button();
        oButton.Top = oForm.Height - 20;
        oButton.Left = 10;
        oForm.Height += 10;
        oForm.Show();
        //Here I wish to wait for oButton to be clicked
```

Comment: Attach an event to the button

Comment: You need the event onclick.

Comment: Adding to @DaveShaw's answer, don't forget to `oForm.Controls.Add (oButton);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `oForm.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()`.

`ShowDialog` will display the dialog modally, the same as `MessageBox.Show()`.

If you want to the button to close the form, you can use the `DialogResult` property:

```
oButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Alternatively, if you do want to use '.Show()`, you can use an event handler to handle the button click and close the form:

```
oButton.Click += (s, e) => { oForm.Close(); };
```